# Class 'Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event' not found, LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy usando laravel 7 y me da el siguiente error, según he buscado por internet para intentar solucionarlo he instalado lo siguiente en mi composer.json y he realizado el composer -update pero me sigue dando el mismo error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

"symfony/event-dispatcher": "^2.7|^3.3.2|^4.0"

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "pixeloution/true-random" : "*",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^2.7|^3.3.2|^4.0"

    },
```

Cuando hago el composer update me da lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias pero no

Comment: El error es muy claro la version de tu paquete `symfony/event-dispatcher` no es compatible con la version de tu laravel, y te da muchas opciones las cuales podrian ser compatibles, iniciando con el 2.7.x-dev

Comment: @Shassain pon eso como respuesta

Comment: @Xerif si sabes de q va no hace falta

Comment: @Shassain Entiendo tengo que ir probando distintas versiones hasta que funcione, graciaas!!